# joomla template: How do I fix all text centered on IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, joomla

Well my template is looking greate on everything there is to be but IE6... (which it is quite normal so far) the issue is my text is align to the center (nowhere in the CSS there is nothing but * {margin:0px auto} that indicated to align anything to center) I'm pissed with this! I've text-align everything I could think of so far and nothing changes... I'll be forever greatful for the answer, i know someone had the same issue at some time... so thank you in advance

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* General Settings */
* {margin:0px auto;
padding:0px;}

body {font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;}

.clear {clear:both;
height:0;
font-size: 1px;
line-height: 0px;}

table {float:left;
text-align:left;}

td {text-align:left;}

html, body, #wrap {height: 100%;}

body > #wrap {height: auto; min-height: 100%;}

p {font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
letter-spacing:1px;
line-height:20px;
text-align:left;}

#invisibleparagraph {color:#FFF;}

img {border:none;}

a {border:none;}

#main {padding-bottom: 150px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

/* Header */
#header {height:120px;
background:#000;
width:100%;}

.header_wrapper {width:960px;
height:120px;}

.logo {float:left;
width:490px;
height:120px;
background:url(../images/Header.jpg) no-repeat;}

.top_modules {float:left;
width:470px;
height:120px;}

.top_module_1 {float:right;
width:400px;
height:60px;
background:url(../images/Search_bg.png) no-repeat top left;}

.top_module_1 .search {height:60px;
background:url(../images/Search_go.png) no-repeat top right;}

.top_module_1 .inputbox {padding-left:20px;
width:330px;
background:none;
border:none;}

.top_module_1 .button {padding-top:10px;
border:none;
background:none;
color:#FFF;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;}


.top_module_2 {float:right;
width:470px;
height:60px;
background:url(../images/Menu_bg.png) no-repeat bottom right;}

/* Content */
#content {width:100%;
background:url(../images/Blast-Template_13.png) repeat-x;}

.Content_wrapper {width:960px;}

/* Left */
.left {float:left;
width:240px;
background:nonce;}

.left .moduletable_menu h3 {text-align:left;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
letter-spacing:5px;
padding-bottom:15px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-left:10px;
color:#F90;}

.left .moduletable_menu li {text-decoration:none;
list-style:none;
color:#000;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
padding-bottom:5px;}

.left .moduletable_menu a {text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
padding-left:10px;
letter-spacing:1px;}

.left .moduletable_menu a:hover {color:#F90}

.left .moduletable_menu a:visited {color:#CCC}

.left .moduletable h3 {text-align:left;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
letter-spacing:5px;
padding-bottom:15px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-left:10px;
color:#F90;}

.left .moduletable ul {padding-bottom:10px;
padding-top:10px;}

.left .moduletable li {text-decoration:none;
list-style:none;
color:#000;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-left:10px;
text-align:left;}

.left .moduletable table {text-align:left;
padding-left:10px;
float:left;}

.left .moduletable a {text-decoration:none;
color:#000;}

.left .moduletable a:hover {color:#C30}

.left .moduletable label {color:#000;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;}

.left .moduletable fieldset {border:none;
padding-left:10px;}

/* Right.Content Area */
.right {float:right;
width:720px;
text-align:left;}

.right .componentheading {padding-left:10px;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
color:#000;
text-align:left;}

.right .contentpaneopen {padding-left:10px;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
text-align:left;}

.right .contentheading {
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
color:#900;
text-align:left;}

.right .small {
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#999;}

.right .createdate, .modifydate {
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:9px;
color:#666;}

.right a {color:#009;
text-decoration:none;}

.right a:visited {color:#006;}

.right a:hover {color:#F90;}

.right .readon {float:right;
display:block;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#00F;}

.right .blog_more {padding-left:10px;}

.right .blog_more li {list-style:none;}
.right .blog_more a {font-size:12px;}


/* Footer Settings */
#footer {position: relative;
margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
height: 150px;
clear:both;
background:#000;}

.footer_wrapper {width:960px;
height:150px;}

.extra1 {float:left;
width:320px;
height:150px;}

.extra1 h3 {padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
display:block;
color:#F60;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
text-align:left;}
.extra1 li {text-decoration:none;}
.extra1 a {text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;}
.extra1 a:hover {color:#69F;}

.extra2 {float:left;
width:320px;
height:150px;}

.extra2 h3 {padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
display:block;
color:#F60;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
text-align:left;}
.extra2 li {text-decoration:none;}
.extra2 a {text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;}
.extra2 a:hover {color:#69F;}

.extra3 {float:right;
width:320px;
height:150px;}

.extra3 h3 {padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
display:block;
color:#F60;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
text-align:left;}
.extra3 li {text-decoration:none;}
.extra3 a {text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;}
.extra3 a:hover {color:#69F;}
.extra3 p {color:#FFF;
text-align:right;
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

IE6 doesn't listen to

```
margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
```

statements to center a DIV. So it could be that as a workaround, there are `<div align="center">` statements **within the html source code**. You may have to overwrite the centering using inline CSS there if the style sheets' settings don't apply.

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear god...

```
.right .contentpaneopen {text-align:left;}
```

is not working so

```
.right .contentpaneopen p {text-align:left;}
```

solves it, god only knows...

Comment: Probably because there is a `<div align=center>` or somesuch in `.contentpaneopen`, as I said.